# no puedo mostrar mapa de google en mi pagina php

Tags: php

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]Tengo un proyecto que estoy creando de venta de agua y quiero al registrar el cliente, registrar también la ubicación de su casa en google map con un marcador y guardarlo en la base de datos lo que no estoy pudiendo es mostrar el mapa osea no me muestra el mapa sale el error
Esta página no puede cargar Google Maps correctamente.
¿Eres el propietario de este sitio web? Aceptar

ya genere la api key

Tengo un proyecto que estoy creando de venta de agua y quiero al registrar el cliente, registrar también la ubicación de su casa en google map con un marcador y guardarlo en la base de datos lo que no estoy pudiendo es mostrar el mapa osea no me muestra el mapa sale el error
Esta página no puede cargar Google Maps correctamente.
¿Eres el propietario de este sitio web? Aceptar

ya genere la api key

```html
    
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Formulario de Usuarios</title>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAhqW8ZWuJ7ePWVuFIfAlMuvIl5Z3m6_t4&callback=initMap" defer></script>
    <style>
        #mapa {
            height: 50vh;
            width: 50vw;
        }
    </style>
    <script>
        var map;
        var marker;

        function initMap() {
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('mapa'), {
                center: {lat: 40.7128, lng: -74.0060},
                zoom: 8
            });

            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: {lat: 40.7128, lng: -74.0060},
                map: map,
                draggable: true
            });

            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function (event) {
                document.getElementById('latitud').value = event.latLng.lat();
                document.getElementById('longitud').value = event.latLng.lng();
            });
        }

        function abrirMapa() {
            var modal = document.getElementById("mapaModal");
            modal.style.display = "block";
            google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
            map.setCenter({lat: 40.7128, lng: -74.0060});
        }

        function cerrarMapa() {
            var modal = document.getElementById("mapaModal");
            modal.style.display = "none";
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Formulario de Usuarios</h1>

<input type="text" id="nombre" placeholder="Nombre">
<input type="text" id="correo" placeholder="Correo">
<input type="text" id="telefono" placeholder="Teléfono">
<br><br>
<button onclick="abrirMapa()">Seleccionar Ubicación en Mapa</button>
<br><br>
<div id="mapaModal" class="modal" style="display: none;">
    <div id="mapa"></div>
    <button onclick="cerrarMapa()">Guardar Ubicación</button>
</div>

<input type="hidden" id="latitud">
<input type="hidden" id="longitud">

<script>
    initMap();
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: ¿Y le has echado un vistazo a los mensajes que te aparecen en la consola del navegador?